# Toggle show/hide of fields on form on custom button click

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm trying to implement a custom button which, when clicked, toggles the visibility of two fields on the form (password and password_confirmation to be hidden/displayed).

I’m able to get an action item button displayed on the form but when this is clicked this error message is displayed:

> Missing template admin/users/toggle_password,
>   active_admin/resource/toggle_password,
>   active_admin/base/toggle_password,
>   inherited_resources/base/toggle_password, application/toggle_password
>   with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[],
>   :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :arb]}.

My admin file:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  menu parent: 'User Management'

  permit_params :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  index do
    selectable_column
    id_column
    column :email
    column :created_at
    actions
  end

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Details" do
      f.input :email
      f.input :password
      f.input :password_confirmation
    end
    f.actions

  end

  action_item :toggle_password, only: %i( show edit ) do
    # Link to perform the member_action "toggle_password" defined below
    link_to 'Toggle Password', action: :toggle_password
  end

  member_action :toggle_password do
    # show/hide password field
  end

end
```

How am I able to link the button click event to call a function of my own?

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, on click of link `Toggle Password`, you are calling the action `toggle_password`.
Rails will try to find corresponding template for the same.

You can toggle field using javascript.
Add an `id` to the link.

```
action_item :toggle_password, only: %i( show edit ) do
  # Link to perform the member_action "toggle_password" defined below
  link_to 'Toggle Password', id: 'link', action: :toggle_password
end
```

In javascript, you can write

```
$('#link').click(function() {
  $(<#id of password & password confirmation field>).toggle();
});
```

Comment: Would this be a javascript file under /views? E.g. app/views/user.js?

Comment: Yes, it will be in javascript file. `app/assets/javascripts/user.js`.
You also have to make an entry in `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file as
     `//= require user`